# Backbone.js router and redirection problems with Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

bit of a weird one and I'm a little baffled...

I have a page, on that page is the following (well, with a few name changes):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var router = new App.Routers.ExampleRouter();
  Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
})
```

The router goes on its way to instantiate some collections, views etc. Everything is working absolutely fine in Chrome, Safari, Firefox and Opera. But not in IE 8 or 9 (maybe 10 too, I haven't tested).

In IE8 or 9 when the page is first requested it starts to load, but as soon as the document is ready (and the router therefore instantiated and History started) the page redirects to the site root.

There's nothing in the console that I can see prior to the redirect. There's no code anywhere else that could be somehow doing it - I mean, we have a large codebase, so it's always a possibility, but there's nothing that deals with routing or the History API that could be conflicting.

The weird part is if the `pushState: true` option is removed, the page doesn't redirect, it loads fully as it should - the router doesn't go on its way to do anything as it's now expecting hashbang style routes, but it at least doesn't kick you back to the site's root. Add the option back in, and it breaks again...

So, my first thought was obviously "Well...the History API isn't supported in IE8 or 9...must be it" but then Backbone.js is supposed to revert back to hashbang style URLs for those older browsers, so it can't be that.

What on earth is causing just IE to redirect back to the homepage when dealing with a Backbone.js router?

**EDIT**

(The below can probably be ignored now as EDIT 2 proves it did nothing, although yay for removing trailing commas)

Okay, so after a little debugging and really clutching at straws I found that the router wasn't actually being instantiated - no initialize method being called, no ability to call custom methods on the router (I'd just made a silly method to `alert` and `console.log`) and called it just after `var router = new App.Routers.ExampleRouter();`.

Calling the method was returning an error along the lines of: "object doesn't support that property or method" (all of this is just IE again, fine in other browsers). This wasn't unique to the router though, I invoked a new model too and did the same things, same thing...just wasn't being "seen". A Google of the object error suggested trailing-commas. Right enough there were some in the codebase, I removed all of them and it seemed like things were going well. All of a sudden the router (and model) were very much there - initialize method called, custom method called etc. I figured the commas may have stopped all of the JS being parsed (we concatenate multiple files).

I'd obviously been doing all of this with the `pushState` option removed. I then added `pushState: true` back in genuinely thinking that would fix it what with the above having happened. I'd thought at the time "Ah, the router never actually 'existed' so maybe `Backbone.History.Start({pushState: true})` being called sent it looking for a route, and none existed due to the router not being instantiated, and the kick-back to the homepage was just some sort of side-effect" but alas, no, the exact same thing is still happening. Add in the `pushState: true` option and the page just doesn't load, and kicks you back to the homepage.

**EDIT 2**

Okay, so I've tried some further things to no avail. I made a completely separate blank page that pulls in jQuery, Backbone.js and Underscore.js via a CDN and contains some barebones JavaScript for creating a router, instantiating it and calling Backbone.History.Start(). The code in it's entirety for that page is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test IE</title>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){

        App = {
          Routers: {

          }
        };

        App.Routers.RouterTest = Backbone.Router.extend({
          routes: {
            "ietest.html" : "helloWorld"
          },

          initialize: function() {
            console.log("router init");
          },

          helloWorld: function() {
            alert("helloWorld!")
          }
        });
        router = new App.Routers.RouterTest();
        Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
      });
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

That's it, completely barebones, no influence from any other site assets etc. The exact same thing still happens. All browsers do what is expected, except IE (tested on 8 and 9) which again starts to load the page, then executes the route and all of a sudden redirected back to the homepage. If I turn pushState off and use hashbangs everything works as expected - so routing does 'work' for me in IE, just not with pushState set to true.

I can't see that this is a front-end thing anymore as I've stripped away everything I can? Is there any way this is a server related thing? The back-end is Ruby on Rails and the problem is exhibited locally and on staging / live servers. Or have I grossly misunderstood the way that Backbone.js degrades pushState to hashbangs with IE?

**EDIT 3**

I've [uploaded a video of the problem](http://www.screencast.com/t/ylQFhKvqLrZ)

Comment: Is it possible to post a demo?

Comment: It is live at [link](http://audacio.us) (locatable by clicking 'Bible Reader', and then clicking a chapter number, this goes to a route similar to 'bible/Gen.3.WEB') but it would mean signing up just to see it, which understandably is a faff.

Comment: Do you have any solution? I am seeing the exact behavior you're describing (a year later, obviously), but I'm not actually using the History module. In fact, if I comment out the whole JS file the page still redirects. Just by including a blank JS file, I can get the page to redirect improperly.

Answer (score 10):

Internet Explorer doesn't support pushState until IE 10, see

http://caniuse.com/#search=pushState

Edit:

To start History with an optional pushState you could go with this:

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState: "pushState" in window.history});
```

Comment: I know, but the Backbone.js docs say: "For browsers which don't yet support the History API, the Router handles graceful fallback and transparent translation to the fragment version of the URL." :(

Comment: @Kerry, I suspect that the Backbone documentation is a bit misleading in this respect.

Comment: Sure fixed the issue for me! Thanks!

Comment: When using Modernizr, you could also use `{pushState: Modernizr.history}`

Answer (score 9):

It looks to me that your application is not being served from the root URL (`/`).

You're requesting `http://example.com/sub/ietest.html`, and Backbone redirects to `http://example.com/#sub/ietest.html`.

You probably want to initialize `Backbone.history` specifying a root URL:

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: '/sub/'});
```

I haven't really dug into the source code of your page (and the JS is minified), but this seems to be the case. Maybe `root: '/bible/'`?

Comment: Sorry if I've misunderstood, but everything is served from '/' as the root, there's no custom root. I tried adding root: '/' as an option just to see, but it changed nothing.

So the bible page (as an example) is reached via this url: audacio.us/bible/Gen.1.WEB and the corresponding route in the router is: "bible/:book.:chapter.:translation".

So sorry if I'm being silly, but where was sub requested?

Comment: By the way, if one bookmarks a hash url, redirects will be a problem in more than one ways - http://tshrestha.blogspot.com/2013/05/hash-bang-url-fragments-and-http.html

Comment: @Kerry: I had the same problem and specifying a root when calling `Backbone.history.start` did solve it. Still trying to figure out why though...

Comment: Apparently Backbone expects the application to be at its root when it is started (when enforcing pushState on IE). Therefore the `location.pathname` has to equal the root option to prevent the browser from redirecting at `Backbone.history.start`.

Answer (score 4):

try to comment all the console.log() calls. In my case that was the problem for ie9. Yes, I'm also asking the question that why :-), very odd

(I didn't use pushState, but that should not matter I guess)

Answer (score 1):

This has seemed to work for me in terms of getting IE8/9 (we don't support 7 at work) to use the hash correctly:

```
var pushState = !!(window.history && window.history.pushState),
    settings = { pushState: pushState, silent: true, hashChange: !pushState ? true : false };
Backbone.history.start(settings);
```

I kept the settings object separate as I was having issues with the services I'm using at work and not returning results for whatever reason.  Whether or not that results issues is from adding this change is still up for debate.  That is also limited to my use case.

also to note for IE is that you now need to handle the hashes for deeplinking.

I use `"silent": true` b/c I'm rendering initial results on page load and this will prevent any calls from happening.  from the backbone docs:

> If the server has already rendered the entire page, and you don't want the initial route to trigger when starting History, pass silent: true.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this option was available when question was originally posted...

I got round this issue for browsers < IE 10 (no support for pushState) by adding option of {hashChange: false} when calling start, as detailed here - http://backbonejs.org/#History-start.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
if(!(window.history && history.pushState)) {
        Backbone.history.start({ pushState: false, silent: true });
        var fragment = window.location.pathname.substr(
            Backbone.history.options.root.length);
        Backbone.history.navigate(fragment, { trigger: true });
    }
    else {
        Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true });
    }
```

Credits go to http://blog.isotoma.com/2014/01/backbone-history-and-ie9/

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me: Backbone.history.start({root: '/my_app_dir_here/'});